# How to "make" existing Linux kernel module driver after modifying the driver source code

Tags: makefile, kernel

I have made some trivial modifications to a Linux USB Wi-Fi card driver to insert some logging (`printk` statements).  I am loosely following [a guide on how to recompile/load the module](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html), which states that I need to execute `make` in order to build the `.ko` file.  There is an existing `Makefile` in the working directory (`/usr/src/linux/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/`), which reads:

```
rtl8187-objs        := dev.o rtl8225.o leds.o rfkill.o

obj-$(CONFIG_RTL8187)   += rtl8187.o

ccflags-y += -Idrivers/net/wireless/rtl818x
```

When I execute `make` inside this directory, I get:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

According to [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html), this means *"that some makefile was found, but it didn't contain any default goal and none was given on the command line. GNU make has nothing to do in these situations."*

So my question is, what does this mean in the context of what I am trying to do, and how do I go about generating the `.ko` file which I am purported to need for the next step?

Comment: you are `make`ing in the wrong directory. Go up one directory and try to `make` again. Keep on going up and `make`ing until it compiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must run *make* from the top directory of the Linux source (*/usr/src/linux/*). Be sure that your driver is included in your */usr/src/linux/.config* file. So, build the kernel with your driver.
If you don't want to rebuild the entire kernel, read more :)

If you want to re-build all modules inside the directory:

```
make M=drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/
```

If you want to re-build a single module inside the directory:

```
make M=drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/ CONFIG_RTL8187=m
```

The *CONFIG_RTL8187* name can be found in *drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/Kconfig* (CONFIG_ + RTL8187)

It should works also this:

```
make drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
```

Comment: so I did a one-off `make` from the `/usr/src/linux` directory without any driver modifications.  I then made a driver modification (added a `printk` statement) and did a `make ./rtl8187.ko` from the `/usr/src/linux/drivers/net/wireless//rtl818x/rtl8187/` directory.  Worked ok first time, but then I made another modification to `dev.c` and tried to `make ./rtl8187.ko` again and I get "make: Nothing to be done for `/usr/src/linux/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko'.".  Any ideas?

Comment: **Always** run `make` from _/usr/src/linux_ . If you built the whole kernel, on the next make it compiles only the modified files. Anyway, use this `make M=drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/ CONFIG_RTL8187=m` to compile the single module. I just test it and I have some errors like this one: 
WARNING: "usb_unanchor_urb" [drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x//rtl8187/rtl8187.ko] undefined!
This because I didn't compile all the other modules required. So, if you will have error like this one, be sure to compile all requested module.