# writing to /dev/uinput (on ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: linux, input, ubuntu-12.04

I'm developing a little program that creates virtual joysticks on linux, with a python front end. It is a fork of [Linux-Virtual-Joystick](https://github.com/ml32/Linux-Virtual-Joystick).

I need to write to dev/uinput in order to create the user-defined joystick.
The file is opened with O_RDWR (I temporarily added read/write access others for the file whilst debugging). When I do

```
write(uifd, &uidev, sizeof(uinput_user_dev));
```

it returns -1 and sets errno to 22(EINVAL). The arguments are correct, and the file was successfully opened.

Did anyone else encounter this problem? I shelved the project for about a month, but I remember that it worked in the last version of Ubuntu.

**Update:** uinput works on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Hello, is uinput module loaded?

Comment: /dev/uinput is present in my system (Lubuntu 11.10), but I can't load uinput module

Comment: uhh.. how do I do that? module, as in shared library?

Comment: Type lsmod into the terminal to see all loaded modules (loadable kernel modules)

Comment: modprobe uinput && lsmod | grep uinput gives nothing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem you have is with access rights to `uinput`. The error message you receive is typical of that and I have seen the identical behaviour before with other devices.

In order to test that assumption, change the `/dev/uinput` permissions to allow access to all:

```
chmod +0666 /dev/uinput
```

Then try again your code. If now it works fine, you will need to make that change permanent, since otherwise it will revert back to the original permissions after reboot.

To do that in a safe fashion, add a rule file to be located at: `/etc/dev/rules.d`

with the following line:

```
KERNEL=="uinput", GROUP="udev_group"
```

To see how a rule file should look like, check the udev rules file located at:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules
```

When ready, add a a group named udev_group and add your user name to it (or any user that is supposed to have write access to `uinput`).

You may need to reboot to get the new rule working.

The outcome would be that any user who's member of that group will have full access to `uinput`, which is exactly what you wanted.

---

to add the group you can install "Users and Groups":

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

and launch it at:

```
Application -> System Tools -> Administration -> Users and Groups**
```

or in terminal:

```
gnome-system-tools
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The trouble is that I tried the program as a superuser, then added o+rw to /dev/uinput to run it as a normal user, attached to gdb in eclipse. It failed at the same point either way. I don't think this is a permissions issue.

Comment: can we add chmod command also into the rule.d file ?. This is because of end users may not aware about setting required access rights for /dev/uinput

Comment: Automatic access for logged-in user: Add file `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-uinput.rules` with contents: `KERNEL=="uinput", TAG+="uaccess"`

Answer (score 0):

Since uinput module is missing, you should consider building it before going further.

I've never rebuilt a Linux kernel module this way, so you can follow the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771818/how-to-make-existing-linux-kernel-module-driver-after-modifying-the-driver-sou/11804929#11804929)

First, you need to get the corresponding Linux source code and headers. Also install *module-init-tools*
Then, change dir to /usr/src/linux and do as root

```
cp /boot/config-* ./.config
make drivers/input/misc/uinput.ko
```

It'll take a minutes to build uinput.ko

Check if it works before move uinput.ko to /lib/modules/<"yourkernelversion">/kernel/drivers/input/misc

```
insmod ./drivers/input/misc/uinput.ko
```

---

### Edit 1:

It seems that since Linux 2.6.35-17.23, [uinput is a built-in module](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/584812). That's why [it's not shown by lsmod](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1369602).

I have just taken a look at your code, and I think the problem is in this line

```
if (write(uifd, &uidev, sizeof(uinput_user_dev) != sizeof(uinput_user_dev)))
```

It should be

```
if (write(uifd, &uidev, sizeof(uinput_user_dev)) != sizeof(uinput_user_dev))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This really puts a damper of things. I was hoping to create a marginally useful toy that works out of the box.

Comment: (should really be an edit) Are you sure uinput is absent? lsmod does not show uinput, but modprobe uinput returns nothing, so it is present, but inactive. I'll try adding it /etc/modules and see what happens after a reboot. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Well... not now. It looks like uinput is actually loaded :/
I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in Ubuntu 14.04 too, from your repo (https://github.com/ferry-/Linux-Virtual-Joystick-cpp) .  I fixed it by zeroing out the device::uidev member in the device constructor in device.h.

memset(&uidev, 0, sizeof(uidev));