# Adding only one driver to linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I know that on the internet I can find same information about "adding one driver to linux kernel" but I can not get it working.
I need to compile an ADV7800driver. It is based on adv7180 driver code.

I put my driver file (adv7800.c) into `/linux_source_folder/drivers/media/platform/mxc/capture` folder. I also add

```
adv7800_converter-objs := adv7800.o
obj-$(CONFIG_MXC_ADV7800_CONVERTER)+=adv7800_converter.o
```

in makefile in the same folder and add information in `Kconfig`file.

Then I go back to /linux_source_folder and do `sudo make menuconfig` and set adv7800 as a module and save config. Then `sudo make defconfig`, then `sudo make -j4 modules` (now waiting about 2 hours) and then `sudo make modules install`.

As a result I can see every module which I configure in `menuconfig` but I can not see my own module (only .c file exists).

How can I do this correctly and how can I build only this one module without building others (to same much time) ?

Comment: After you run `make menuconfig` (_after_ `make defconfig` as @Federico mentioned), you can check your `.config` file (in the kernel's root directory) to make sure `MXC_AXC_ADV7800_CONVERTER` is set before building -- saves you having to wait two hours to figure out if you've done it right.

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember exactly what happens in terms of instructions executed, but the idea of `defconfig` is to set a *default configuration* for a given architecture/platform.

If, as you said, you run `sudo make defconfig` **after** you configure your module to be compiled, most likely you loose your configuration. The `defconfig` should be executed first (once) and then you customize the configuration.

Regarding the compilation of a single module, I point you to an old answer

[How to "make" existing Linux kernel module driver after modifying the driver source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771818/how-to-make-existing-linux-kernel-module-driver-after-modifying-the-driver-sou/11804929#11804929).

One note: you should not use `sudo` to compile

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try.